# Display a static image as a header in Setting.apk

Tags: android, imageview

I want to simply add a new header-style line in Settings top-level.  Not an icon, like the other entries have to the left of the section text, but a screen-width image.  This would be implemented elsewhere, but for now, I just want to be able to have an image be shown at all

This does not seem to be easily done, and I have not found a complete guide for something this simple anywhere.

For this I will need both the XML edits, AND the matching java counterpart.

Here is my current Java part:

```
    setImageDrawable(R.id.logo);
```

And this is my XML side:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/romlogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

My image is currently in `/res/drawable-xhdpi/`, and is named `"romlogo.png" (461 x 113)`

As it sits, it doesn't even compile.  Not sure if I'm missing an `import` or what.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse a `Drawable` to the `setImageDrawable(...)` method. However, the XML code looks good. Do not set the image programmatically, it is already there stated in the property `android:src="@drawable/romlogo"`. If you want to set it with code use something like this:

```
// fetch the imageview and afterwards set the drawable
// here consider the difference between R.id and R.drawable
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.romlogo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#000"
android:gravity="center" >
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:paddingTop="0.1dp"
android:paddingLeft="0.1dp"
android:paddingRight="0,1dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:id="@+id/iv"
android:src="@drawable/organic"
android:layout_weight="30"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will be the XML code for the appropriate output.[Image as an header and of screen width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jzsi.png)

Comment: No need of any JAVA code if you want to keep the image static.